# Select Query Using Column Headers From Another Query and max

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a list of column headings from another query,

I have tried the below but unable to achieve the result

```
SELECT 
    Submission_Number, Form_Type, 
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS full_count,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'CheckName' THEN Feild_Value end) as Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'CheckAltName' THEN Feild_Value END) as AltName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'CheckDate' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'CheckTime' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'CheckArea' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Area,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'CheckLine' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Line,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = 'FormTime' THEN Feild_Value END) AS FormTime,
    SELECT 'max(case when Feild_ID = '+DATA_UID+' then Feild_Value end) as "'+Data_Text+'",' FROM Check_Form WHERE Form_Constraint = 'PU_CS' ORDER BY Data_UID ASC
FROM 
    [dbo].[Check_Core]
WHERE 
    Form_Type = 'PU_CS'
GROUP BY  
    Submission_Number, Form_Type
ORDER BY Submission_Number DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 25 ROWS ONLY
```

The output of

```
SELECT 'max(case when Feild_ID = '+DATA_UID+' then Feild_Value end) as "'+Data_Text+'",' FROM Check_Form WHERE Form_Constraint = 'PU_CS' ORDER BY Data_UID ASC
```

Is

```
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_001 then Feild_Value end) as "Machine",
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_002 then Feild_Value end) as "Product",
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_003 then Feild_Value end) as "Pour",
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_004 then Feild_Value end) as "Colour",
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_005 then Feild_Value end) as "Time",
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_006 then Feild_Value end) as "Level (%)",
max(case when Feild_ID = CS_007 then Feild_Value end) as "Condition",
```

Comment: I"m sorry, but I don't understand what you're attempting to do

Comment: I'm attempting to create another series of max statements from another query

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Try to [edit] your question with proper sample data and expected results.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be **field** - rather than "feild" ?

Comment: And the problem you have is? stackoverflow is not supposed to be a game of charades, better describe exactly what the issue is right away

Comment: Always pains me to see "Machine".  Use [Machine] or quotename(Data_Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for this. Make sure to use `QUOTENAME` to quote columns correctly, and make sure to pass in data using parameters.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT 
    Submission_Number, Form_Type, 
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS full_count,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''CheckName'' THEN Feild_Value end) as Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''CheckAltName'' THEN Feild_Value END) as AltName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''CheckDate'' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''CheckTime'' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''CheckArea'' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Area,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''CheckLine'' THEN Feild_Value END) AS Line,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ''FormTime'' THEN Feild_Value END) AS FormTime' +
(
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Feild_ID = ' + QUOTENAME(DATA_UID, '''') + ' THEN Feild_Value END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Data_Text)
    AS nvarchar(max)), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Data_UID ASC)
  FROM Check_Form
  WHERE Form_Constraint = 'PU_CS'
) + '
FROM 
    [dbo].[Check_Core]
WHERE 
    Form_Type = ''PU_CS''
GROUP BY  
    Submission_Number, Form_Type
ORDER BY Submission_Number DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 25 ROWS ONLY;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that `COUNT(*) OVER ()` will only give you the count for the final resultset, unless you embed it in a subquery in which case it will be very inefficient as it will run on the whole table.